# Why isn't my React child component receiving new props?

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-lifecycle

I have a React component that acts as a sortable table. The table header and the table rows are children of a container, and the container is handling the state of the table. When a header is clicked, the data is re-ordered just like it is in [this semantic-ui-react example](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table#table-example-sortable).

```
handleSort = (clickedColumn) => {
const { column, orders, direction } = this.state

if (column !== clickedColumn) {
  this.setState({
    column: clickedColumn,
    orders: customSort(orders, clickedColumn),
    direction: 'ascending',
  })
} else {
this.setState({
  orders: orders.reverse(),
  direction: direction === 'ascending' ? 'descending' : 'ascending',
})}
```

The first time I click a column header, the first closure runs, and `this.setState` changes the state of the container, and triggers the children to receive new props and update accordingly. If I re-click the column header to reverse the order of the data, the second closure runs, and `this.setState` updates the state of the container. Accordingly, the child component `OverviewTableHeader` updates, but `OverviewTableRows` does not.

```
render() {
const { designers, orders, column, direction } = this.state
if (orders === "loading"){
  return <Loading />
} 
const tableRows = <OverviewTableRows  
                     designers={designers} 
                     orders={this.state.orders}
                     />
debugger
return (
  <div className="overview">
    <Table selectable fixed sortable>
      <OverviewTableHeader sort={this.handleSort} column={column} direction={direction}/>
      {tableRows}
    </Table>
  </div>
  ) 
}
```

[Here's a video of this in action.](https://youtu.be/3vwRj1E62CQ)

In the video, you can see `OverviewTableRows` trigger `componentWillReceiveProps` and `shouldComponentUpdate` the first time `setState` is triggered in the parent, but not the second.

I can add all of my code if needed. Is this a bug? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by making a copy of the array before reversing it and using it to update the state.

```
handleSort = (clickedColumn) => {
const { column, orders, direction } = this.state

if (column !== clickedColumn) {
  this.setState({
    column: clickedColumn,
    orders: customSort(orders, clickedColumn),
    direction: 'ascending',
  })
} else {
  const reversedOrders = orders.slice().reverse();
this.setState({
  orders: reversedOrders,
  direction: direction === 'ascending' ? 'descending' : 'ascending',
})}
```

I guess the identity of the array `orders` mattered. I'm guessing this has to do with the functional nature of React. I hope this helps somebody! If anybody has a good explanation of why this is the case, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good quote that may explain what's going on.

> By manipulating this.state directly you are circumventing React’s state management, which can be potentially dangerous as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made.

Taken from [this article](https://medium.com/pro-react/a-brief-talk-about-immutability-and-react-s-helpers-70919ab8ae7c).

Since `orders` is an mutable object and a member of `state`, you are altering the state directly when you call `orders.reverse` (even if this reordering is being done within a `setState` call).

So, yes, your solution of creating a copy of `orders` will solve this issue because you are no longer altering `this.state` directly.